# Why in this openCL kernel code the `localSum` is local?

Tags: opencl

Unfortunately the page I'm using as [reference](https://dournac.org/info/gpu_sum_reduction) is in french.

There's this kernel:

```
  __kernel void sumGPU ( __global const double *input, 
                         __global double *partialSums,
                         __local double *localSums)
 {
  uint local_id = get_local_id(0);
  uint group_size = get_local_size(0);

  // Copy from global to local memory
  localSums[local_id] = input[get_global_id(0)];

  // Loop for computing localSums : divide WorkGroup into 2 parts
  for (uint stride = group_size/2; stride>0; stride /=2)
     {
      // Waiting for each 2x2 addition into given workgroup
      barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

      // Add elements 2 by 2 between local_id and local_id + stride
      if (local_id < stride)
        localSums[local_id] += localSums[local_id + stride];
     }

  // Write result into partialSums[nWorkGroups]
  if (local_id == 0)
    partialSums[get_group_id(0)] = localSums[0];
 }
```

Where the idea is to perform a parallel sum (which would cost O(log n) instead of O(n)).
My only question is why the `localSums` is declared as `__local`? Can this code be further optimized?

I'm just confused because in general I would declare local variables inside the kernel, while instead in this specific example the host specifies the size and passes `NULL` as argument of the `clSetKernelArg`.

The line is the following (host side)

```
   // Create the OpenCL kernel
   cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "sumGPU", &ret);

   // Set the arguments of the kernel
   clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&inputBuffer);
   clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&reductionBuffer);
   clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, local_item_size*sizeof(double),NULL);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My only question is why the localSums is declared as local? Can this code be further optimized?

Note how the following line accesses another work item's "slot" in the array.

```
   localSums[local_id] += localSums[local_id + stride];
```

The only way to do this is with local or global memory, and local memory is undoubtedly more efficient than global.

> I'm just confused because in general I would declare local variables inside the kernel, while instead in this specific example the host specifies the size and passes NULL as argument of the clSetKernelArg.

If you declare a `local` buffer in your kernel, its size must be fixed at compile time. Setting the size of the local buffer dynamically via a kernel argument means you can use the same kernel code with different group sizes.

Local buffers must always be initialised from within the kernel, so passing `NULL` as the argument pointer on the host side is correct.